# Execution flow, transactions and MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, innodb

I want to know if stored procedure in MySQL is something more than sequence of SQL statements with some restrictions (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

Is there something special with transactions, DML on InnoDB tables etc.?

As far as I know it isn't, because I failed to find out opposite.

Edit:

Execution flow is also an interesting question.

Assume I have simple following procedure and autocommit is off:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someproc ()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   -- exec stmt1
    ->   -- exec stmt2  <--- assume it fails!
    ->   -- exec stmt3
    -> END//
```

What happens if stmt2 fails during execution for some reason?

In my opinion stmt2 changes will be rollbacked, but stmt1 changes are not and execution flow of procedure will be stopped so stmt3 won't be execute.

Comment: You must be having a reason why you're asking this. It might help if you told us why you're after this information, it appears to be an XY problem going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MySQL stored program supports syntax beyond SQL statements, such as declaring variables, conditional branching, loops, cursors, dynamic SQL, etc. In that sense, it is more than a sequence of SQL statements.

There's nothing "special" about DML statements on InnoDB tables or transactions in a MySQL stored program. A PROCEDURE is the most lenient in terms of allowed oprations. There are some restrictions on FUNCTIONS and TRIGGERS (as as you have found). The restrictions mostly stem from how functions get called (as an expression within a statement, or how triggers get fired (when a DML statement is executing.)

---

**EDIT**

Unless a HANDLER is declared to catch an exception/error, when an error is encountered within a MySQL stored PROCEDURE, the execution of the procedure stops and the error is returned to the caller.

As far was what DML changes are committed or rolled back, that depends on whether the tables are MyISAM or not, and whether auto commit is enabled. or on whether a COMMIT or ROLLBACK is issued for the transaction. It doesn't matter whether the DML statement is executed within a stored procedure, or outside of a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure can be seen as a group of SQL statements to be executed as one single transaction.

The transaction nature is important when dealing with concurrency.

Another benefit of having a stored procedure is to apply access control to the stored procedure.

Comment: As far as I know stored procedure is not a transaction in a formal meaning, you should make it explicitly if you want so. If you mean in a logical way - may be it is.

Comment: It depends on which SQL database is in used. MySql might require explicit transaction handling commands in a stored procedure. But Oracle and MS SQL Server don't. You don't have to explicitly start a transaction, it is done automatically. You will have to specify the end of the transaction with a commit (or a rollback).